# Does Microsoft support OpenID?

Tags: openid

Does anyone know whether Microsoft supports or plans to support OpenID?

I am asking this because I need to decide whether  or not to use OpenID in my new product, and it's very important to me that my user can use Hotmail.

Comment: I will never understand why someone put a down vote without telling why, Are you smarter that me , probably, so please let me know what I am doing wrong!!!!

Comment: That annoys me too.  In this case I would speculate the downvote was because the question is only tangentially programming related, and the answer can be found easily with Google.  Still I would not have downvoted, just made a comment similar to this one.

Comment: I'm going to guess you were down voted because your question doesn't appear (in my opinion) to be programming related. I'm basing that on the fact you've made no reference to any programming languages. If your question is programming related, maybe you could elaborate your question a little to show this. - p.s. I didn't down vote you. Edit: +1 as you've edited your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Live ID is not an OpenID Provider, nor are (most) Microsoft sites OpenID relying parties.

Microsoft is still researching OpenID adoption.  I expect they will become an OpenID Provider eventually, but no date has been announced as far as I know.

Comment: This is an out of date answer - OpenID Connect is supported as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Answer (score 1):

[First result  on Google for request "microsoft openid"](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/microsoft_windows_live_openid.php)

Comment: But this result is from October 27, 2008 1:18 PM, I was asking if anyone has any more present news.

Comment: @Jedi Master Spooky here's an update from last August.http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1791.entry

Comment: I Accept this answer for the Comment. Thanks @Chris

Comment: The blog referenced by @TooManyCooks is dead. It looks like there is no current OpenID implementation for Windows Live.

Comment: This is an out of date answer - OpenID Connect is supported as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/